# Get visible rows in a TCL/ Tk tablelist

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a tcl/tk [tablelist](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html#containing) in my  application where large number of rows can be represent. I have a scrodget associated with the table so a scrollbar appears when the element count is larger than a current tablesize.

```
    ttk::labelframe .frm -text "Frametitle"
    ttk::scrodget .frm.sc -autohide both

    tablelist::tablelist .frm.lb -selectmode $selectmode -columntitles $columns

    .frm.sc associate .frm.lb
    grid .frm.sc -row 0 -column 0 -sticky nsew
    grid .frm
```

Now my problem is for large number of element, my customized periodic update procedure is taking a long time. So instead of all the elements, I only want to update the rows currently visible. Is there any method getting the elements in the current view.

The substitute is implementing some kind of page like feature for the table. But I will think about that as last resort. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of combining the right [row indices](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html#row_indices) with the [`index`](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html#index) method.
You can get the topmost visible row with:

```
.frm.lb index top
```

and the bottom-most visible row with:

```
.frm.lb index bottom
```